# Swift 2.x to swift 3, XCode complaining error : 'String!' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

When migrating from Swift 2.x to swift 3, I have the error "'String!' is not convertible to 'String'" which appears on line

```
self.cartItemController.textCombinationsToDisplayInCart[pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as String]=combinationValue["Name"]
```

Does any one a an idea how to correct this?

```
func setTextCombinationsToDisplayInCart(_ pCombinationsPickerView:CombinationsPickerView,pRow:Int) {
    var combinationValue:[NSString : NSObject]=pCombinationsPickerView.combinationValues[pRow] as! [NSString : NSObject]
    if(pCombinationsPickerView.combinationID != 1) { //Personnalisation 
        self.cartItemController.textCombinationsToDisplayInCart[pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as String]=combinationValue["Name"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `myVar as String` returns `String?` instead of `String`.

You can instead use `myVar as! String`, if you are sure that this conversion will always work.

However, if you are afraid that the forced typecast might return nil optional, you can try a `guard` statement.

Comment: I replace : [pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as String] by [pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as! String] but now it warnings by : "Forced cast from 'string!' to 'String' always succed, did you mead to use 'as' ? And Xcode proposes to replace by 'as!' by 'as'...

Comment: The issue is probably on the right hand side. The `combinationValue["Name"]` is an `NSString`. You need to use `as` conversion for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I resolved the error by this : I replace self.cartItemController.textCombinationsToDisplayInCart[pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as String]=combinationValue["Name"] by self.cartItemController.textCombinationsToDisplayInCart[pCombinationsPickerView.combinationName as NSString]=combinationValue["Name"]